# Confused about using a service versus Asycn Task?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

so I'm making a tinder like app. And everytime the user swipes right on a card, I want to add that card into a pre designated folder and I want that done in the background. So while the user is swiping through cards, in the background I'm adding that card into a folder. Now I'm concerned whether I should use:
a)Create a separate Thread class
b)Create an Async task (but this is only good for work that takes a couple seconds)
c)Create a service. (But this is not on a seperate thread, so im hesitant on using this method).

I don't want the user to wait until the card is into a folder than swipe again. I want them to continuously swipe cards while those cards they swiped get added to the correct folder.

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: @MsYvette I mean, I want to hear other people's opinions. There's nothing wrong with that. And I believe that stackOverflow is a great site to get insight on other people's approaches to problems. And it may help someone else out there trying to do things that may be similar to what i'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scope of the background folder move, I would say. If the folder is local and there is no relatively (few seconds of wait time) immediate impact on the GUI or the GUI will be regenerated before it matters use a thread.

If the results of the move to a folder is going to have an influence on the upcoming GUI actions, and will only make a couple of external (network) calls then an AsyncTask.

If you're doing what I think you are (I'm not familiar with Tinder so I don't really know) then AsyncTask might be best. Load the next  images/profiles and AsyncTask the feedback. When the AsyncTask onPostExecute comes back load the next image/profile in the queue.

A service seems a little heavy-duty for this. But I could be wrong. From the docs on AsyncTask:

```
This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
```

Since this sounds like what you want to do (the results of the swipe published to a server, wait for a response with the next profile based on whatever the remote server provides) I'd look there first.